# syntax error in Typescript when adding onTouchTap to div

Tags: typescript, reactjs

Using Typescript, in a .tsx file, after

```
import injectTapEventPlugin = require('react-tap-event-plugin')
injectTapEventPlugin()
```

with this JSX:

```
<div onTouchTap={ this.showFront }>
```

I get the syntax error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'onTouchTap' does not exist on type 'HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>'.
```

in spite of having

```
interface HTMLDivElement {

    onTouchTap: Function,

}
```

in the same code file, which should merge onTouchTap into the HTMLDivElement interface used by div in lib.d.ts

The intellisense is seeing `onTouchStart` etc, but not `onTouchTap`.

Is there something wrong, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,

- Henrik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in the same code file, which should merge onTouchTap into the HTMLDivElement interface used by div in lib.d.ts

No. Because your file is a module as you have a root level `import` (`import injectTapEventPlugin`). Which means its disconnected from the global namespace

Also the interface you want to extend is not HTMLDivElement but the DOM attributes defined in `react.d.ts`.

## FIX

You need to create a `vendor.d.ts` and put this inside:

```
declare module __React{
    interface DOMAttributes {
        onTouchTap?: Function,
    }
}
```

More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Comment: This is halfway there -- the actual type you need to augment is `__React.DOMAttributes`, not `HTMLDivElement`. The JSX types are not the same as the DOM types (they differ in a bunch of names).

Comment: Ha! @basarat that worked beautifully, and what's more it makes sense!! Thanks so much! actually I had to do `declare module __React {
    interface DOMAttributes {
        onTouchTap?: Function,
    }
}` with the declare and '?', but those are just quibbles

Comment: @HenrikBechmann thanks. I've updated the answer to take those changes into account for future visitors

Comment: This isn't working for me and I've no idea why :/ The @types/react file has React and not __React but changing that doesn't seem to help and in fact it seems to make typescript forget about everything else in the react namespace.